# CakePHP Minify plugin and denying access to original files under webroot

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

We use CakePHP 2.7.9 and Minify plugin on a CentOS server running Apache 2.2.
https://github.com/maurymmarques/minify-cakephp

The plugin works fine and now we can minify css files like this.

```
echo $this->Minify->css(array('default', 'global'));
```

The code above generates URL like this.

```
http://example.com/min-css?f=default.css,global.css
```

And now we want to deny access to original files under webroot/css.  How can it be done in CakePHP?  We want to return 404 or 401 or something like that for direct URL access like this.

```
http://example.com/css/default.css
```

Answer (score 0):

> And now we want to deny access to original files under webroot/css

Simply don't but non public code and files into the public webroot. It's not recommended in any case. Point your minifier to the files and set its output folder to webroot.

We use task runners and keep the minification code outside of the actual app. This is stuff that doesn't belong into the application itself - IMHO.

We use php Robo and on the JS side Gulp for minification and automatically trigger the tasks on deployment. All our SCSS and JS files are outside of the webroot. We have just a few asset includes in our app code and they almost never change. Robo and Gulp have watchers that rewrite the asset files as we change them on when the app is deployed it automatically generates minified files.